# Which class ideally assigns properties: User or UserFactory?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, factory-pattern

I have a class `User` and a class `UserFactory` (factory pattern). The factory connects to SQL and creates instances of the user object.

Since we often have to preprocess fields retrieved from the database, I'm wondering which is the best place to do so. For example (simplified):

```
class UserFactory {
    function getUserByID($id) {
        $q = $this->DB->query("SELECT id, name, email FROM user WHERE id = ?", $id);

        if(!$q)
            return FALSE;

        return new User($q);
    }
}

class User {
    function __construct($obj) {
        if(!empty($obj->id))    $this->ID    = (int) $obj->id;
        if(!empty($obj->name))  $this->name  = $obj->name;
        if(!empty($obj->email)) $this->email = $this->verifyEmail($obj->email);
    }
}
```

In this example the `User` object does the actual processing, but I dislike how I'm still forced to use the actual SQL field names in the `User` object while I have this `UserFactory` designed to be a layer between SQL and PHP.

So I could move the processing to the `UserFactory` like so:

```
class UserFactory {
    function getUserByID($id) {
        $q = $this->DB->query("SELECT id, name, email FROM user WHERE id = ?", $id);

        if(!$q)
            return FALSE;

        $user = new User($q->id);
        $user->setName($q->name);
        $user->setEmail($q->email);

        return $user;
    }
}

class User {
    function __construct($id) {
        $this->ID = (int) $id;
    }

    function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $this->verifyEmail($email);
    }
}
```

I guess this would be a good way to do things, except now I'm making additional function calls for each property which seems unnecessary, and I have to set a list of properties manually with each `UserFactory` function I create.

Where would I ideally process these fields and assign them to the object? What is the 'accepted way'? Would I create a setter for each property, or add multiple arguments to the `User` class constructor... I'd like to hear your ideas.

(I know these 'ideal code style' questions can be subjective and hope I'm not breaking any community guidelines with this.)

Comment: If you had different parameters for each property in the User constructor you could abstract the field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserFactory` is not really a Factory class but a [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

So your second example is right because the domain model should not know anything about the database. You could also combine it with a [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html).

More on this subject: http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/not-blog/why-use-table-data-gateways/

Comment: Good call, I guess it's a Factory and a Data Mapper at the same time. I have different user classes based on their capabilities, e.g. `UserAdmin`, `UserAuthor`...

Comment: What if users have tens of fields though? Would you create a setter for each property or create a separate function to handle all processing at once?

Comment: one nice way is the recommendation from zend framework. You have a `setOptions` method that take an array with all fields. [Create a Model and Database Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html). (scroll down to the middle)

Comment: but yes, it's always nice to have "real" getter and setter methods instead of magic getters/setters.

Comment: Thanks @redreggae, nice examples. Say we have an array with email addresses that is serialized before SQL storage. Would I first have the data mapper unserialize, then use `setEmailAddresses($array)`? Or would I unserialize inside the setter?

Comment: `setEmailAddresses($array)` is the way to go. remember that the model should not be aware of the underlying data storage. and you probably only serialize/unserialize because the data source in this case is a database. But it also could be a webservice or file etc. So the mapper is responsible for transfering the model data to a suitable format. So you would serialize/unserialize in the mapper..

Comment: I guess it has some overlap. In the example link you posted, they use internal typecasting `__construct($id) {$this->ID = (int) $id;}` rather than external `new User((int) $query->id)`, if you catch my drift. But for serialized arrays I agree the user object should not need to be aware of the storage format. Thanks for your help and ideas!